# freeze columns in Flexigrid

Tags: jquery, css

how to freeze(fixed) columns in [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info)

I need to fix first two column in flexigrid while scrolling the div..

Comment: any one who know the answer for this question..???

Answer (score 1):

You can't freeze two columns alone in table, the only way is you need to use `div's` instead of `table`